# DNS or Hostname - seems to change whether a machine can be accessed or not

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, file-sharing

So I work on a large environment with multiple countries and a large DNS structure.

Because of this we sometimes have issues where machines that have not been on the network for a while keep the same IP that has been reallocated to another PC.

For example on Monday Laptop005 gets the IP 10.100.1.50 and Laptop010 gets IP 10.100.1.80, then Laptop005 is taken home for a week and the following Monday Laptop010 gets 10.100.1.50.

However DNS still has an A record for Laptop005 on the same IP so pinging Laptop005 returns 10.100.1.50 as well as Laptop010.

It doesn't cause us any problems however when I'm trying to check who the machine belongs by browsing to `C:\users` using the network share I cannot access `\\laptop005\c$` however I can access `\\10.100.1.50\c$` and then I can check the username and realize it is Joe Bloggs machine which is actually Laptop010 which works with `\\laptop010\c$`.

So my question is what is causing this to not work on browsing `\\laptop005\c$` my understanding is that DNS simply points a hostname to an IP and shouldn't have any relevance on whether or not you can connect to a machine so why does it stop me browsing this on the incorrect hostname?

Comment: So are laptop 5 and 10 are both in your network when you try to access them using the \\hostname?

Comment: No when this happens one machine will be outside the network as soon as that machine comes back it gets assigned a new IP. It is almost as if the aging process in DNS does not clear old records but waits for that machine to be on the network again to assign another, its odd. As mentioned below I do not have admin rights over the DNS settings. It just strikes me as strange that I cannot access any hostname \\hostname\c$ if the ping returns the correct IP. I could enter a hostname in my local host file and this would work so why not across the network like this?

Comment: Yeh thats kinda strange. You could try to empty you local dns cache before tying to access to other maschine.

Answer (score 0):

I see that the dns configuration dosent bother you at all but i would consider changing the dns setting so that the DNS does not store two different hostnames with one IP.

I would look for DNS entry aging and auto removement.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770850.aspx

If your dns configuration is fine you should have no trouble accessing the laptops using \hostname\C$

Comment: Sadly I'm not the administrator of this side of the network or I definitely would have it working better than this is :) they also do not use Windows based DNS they use a third party DNS Server not sure exactly what the device is called...

Comment: Doesent matter what system runs on it there must be an aging setting or automatic cleanup action